# OpenCV YAML: how to read and write nested (recursive) yaml files

Tags: c++, opencv, yaml

I am wanting to write a nested yaml file. Something similar to this:

```
features:
      x: 103
      y: 166
      lbp: "no"
      depth: 
             cam1: "no"
             cam2: "yes"
             lidar: "yes"
      dim: 3
```

I have a code to write simple structure, however I cannot understand how to write nested with it.
I found a way to read nested yaml: https://answers.opencv.org/question/93257/yml-file-reading-complex-structure/

However cant seem to find how to write nested yaml.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const string out_fname = "/tmp/test.yaml";

    cout << "Write YAML file: " << out_fname << endl;
    cv::FileStorage opencv_file( out_fname, cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
    cv::Mat file_matrix;
    file_matrix = (cv::Mat_<int>(3, 3) << 1, 2, 3,
                                            3, 4, 6,
                                            7, 8, 9);
    opencv_file << "my_matrix" << file_matrix;

    opencv_file << "noise" << 43.3;
    opencv_file << "noise_type" << "Gaussian";
    opencv_file << "dim" << 3;

    // doesnt seem to work....!
    // opencv_file["feature"]["camera"] = 2.3;
    // opencv_file["feature"]["imu"] = 10;

    opencv_file.writeComment("a double value", 0);



    opencv_file.release();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const string out_fname = "/tmp/test.yaml";

    cout << "Write YAML file: " << out_fname << endl;
    cv::FileStorage opencv_file( out_fname, cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
    cv::Mat file_matrix;
    file_matrix = (cv::Mat_<int>(3, 3) << 1, 2, 3,
            3, 4, 6,
            7, 8, 9);
    opencv_file << "my_matrix" << file_matrix;

    opencv_file << "noise" << 43.3;
    opencv_file << "noise_type" << "Gaussian";
    opencv_file << "dim" << 3;

    opencv_file << "feature";                             
    opencv_file << "{" << "camera" << 2.3;
    opencv_file <<        "imu" << 10 << "}";
    opencv_file.release();
}
```

Output:

```
%YAML:1.0
my_matrix: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: i
   data: [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
noise: 4.3299999999999997e+01
noise_type: Gaussian
dim: 3
feature:
   camera: 2.2999999999999998e+00
   imu: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In later versions (3.4.11+), there is a pair of methods called `startWriteStruct()` and `endWriteStruct()` that allow writing nested structures with FileStorage.